# if a function $f$ is decreasing and the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ exists, then

Tags: real-analysis

Given that function $f$ is decreasing and the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ exists

How can I prove $$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} x\left(f(x)-f(x+1)\right)$$ exists?

I applied monotone convergence theorem, but there is no way...

Comment: Are you given that $f$ has any nice properties? Is $f$ continuous?  Differentiable?

Comment: You need state the domain and range of the function clearly, otherwise it does not make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false. Counterexample:

Define $f(x)$ this way, for each positive integer $n$ then for all $n^{2}<x\leq (n+1)^{2}$ then $f(x)=-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i^{2}}$. Clearly $f(x)$ is bounded below (bounded by $-\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}$) and monotone decreasing.

Thus whenever $x=(n+1)^{2}$ then $x(f(x+1)-f(x))=x(-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{i^{2}}-(-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i^{2}}))=(n+1)^{2}\frac{-1}{(n+1)^{2}}=-1$. But most of the time, (whenever $x=(n+1)^{2}-1$ for example) $x(f(x+1)-f(x))=0$ instead. Hence this oscillate, so limit does not exist.

Comment: How about if $f$ is strictly decreasing? Though I think your example can be modified to handle this by changing $f$ by very small amounts in the regions where it is now constant. So I'll upvote you.

Comment: Very easily fixed. Just add $e^{-x}$ to the above counter example. Then whenever $x=(n+1)^{2}$ then $x(f(x+1)-f(x))<-1$, and for $x=(n+1)^{2}-1$ then $x(f(x+1)-f(x))$ become arbitrary close to $0$ at sufficiently large $n$, so it still oscillate.

Comment: @martycohen: also,  if you want infinite differentiability this is also doable too: instead of jumping down simply use smooth transition function, since we have the whole interval of length 1 to do it.